# Getting Date from getTimeInMillis when using Databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, formatting, android-databinding

I have a `timeInMillis` value, which I know I can get a `Date` from with something like;

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(dateInMillis)));
```

I'm using `DataBinding` to populate a `RecyclerView`. I am also aware that I can manipulate strings when using `DataBinding` with something like this;

```
android:text='@{String.format("%.1f", example.double)}'
```

However, I cannot work out how to populate the `TextView` with a formatted `Date`from my `timeInMillis` value.

Comment: Why not myTextView.setText(dateString) to your TextView programmatically? Still looking into Databinding, not sure if that is allowed or not. Looks like your trying to set format of the TextView in the XML?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add in your model a function which it can transform your timeInMillis to a formatted Date.

**In your model used in dataBinding layout :**

```
public String getDateFormatted(){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    return formatter.format(new Date(dateInMillis)));;
}
```

**In your layout :**

```
<layout>
   <data>
      <variable name="yourModel"
                type="com.example.model.yourModel"/>
   </data>
...
<TextView 
...
   android:text="@{yourModel.dateFomatted}"
/>
```

Answer (score 33):

I think that putting the format in resources is best approach:

```
<string name="format">%1$td/%1$tm/%1$tY</string>
```

And you would bind the value to the resource like this:

```
<TextView ... android:text="@{@string/format(model.date)}" />
```

Comment: Clean, I like it - Thank you!

Comment: Good answer. [Here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter#dt) for more options on formatting (e.g., I wanted a format like "Jan 1, 2020" so I used "%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY").

Comment: Is there some way of using this with the time format of the device's locale?

Answer (score 0):

As George Mount said, you can use native string format resources to deal with it.

Here I show some examples I finally implemented:

```
<string name="formatter_date">%1$td/%1$tm/%1$tY</string>
<string name="formatter_time">%1$tH:%1$tM</string>
```

First is 01/01/2000

Second is 00:00

All the documentation is [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter#dt)