# How to change date format using room?

Tags: android

I'm using Room that I retrieve its data from Firebase Realtime database I have "requests" node which contains date node the code works fine but i want to change the date format to "dd-mm-yyyy" 
How can I do that ?

```
public class DateTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long value) {
        if(null == value){
         return null;
        }else {
            Date date = new Date(value);
            return date;
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toLong(Date value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.getTime();
    }
}
```

Edit: 
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42604221/5862361)

> I think that putting the format in resources is best approach

Comment: Do you want "dd-mm-yyyy" format while your showing Date??

Comment: yes, I also using data binding

Answer (score 0):

1. Room storing date in `long` data type and returning it in `Date` data type.
2. Now to show this date you need to convert it into `String` with "dd-mm-yyyy" format.

You can do this with using `SimpleDateFormat` class in Java.

```
public static String formatDate(Date date) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
        // Apply desired format here
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        c.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
        return dateFormat.format(c.getTimeInMillis());
    }
```

Now as commented you are using Databinding, you can call this static function directly while setting text for your `TextView`

Hope this help you!!!